# Convert a java string to an xml that contains valid utf-8 characters

Tags: java, xml, utf-8

Here is what I was doing -

1. Take up a document(JSON) from mongodb
2. Write this key value as an XML
3. Send this XML to Apache Solr for indexing

Here is how I was doing step #2

Given key say "key1" and value as "value1" step#2 output is

```
"<"+ key1 + ">" + value1 + "</"+ key1 + ">"
```

Now when i send this XML to Solr, I was getting Stax exceptions like -

1. Invalid UTF-8 start byte 0xb7
2. Invalid UTF-8 start byte 0xa0
3. Invalid UTF-8 start byte 0xb0
4. Invalid UTF-8 start byte 0x96

So here is how I am thinking to fix it -

```
key1New = new String(key1.getBytes("UTF-8"), "UTF-8");
value1New = new String(value1.getBytes("UTF-8"), "UTF-8");
```

Should this work OR I should rather do this -

```
key1New = new String(key1.getBytes("UTF-8"), "ISO-8859-1");
value1New = new String(value1.getBytes("UTF-8"), "ISO-8859-1");
```

Comment: Try `new String(bytes, Charset.forName("UTF-8"))`

Comment: Don't create the XML yourself to start with - use an XML API. And if you've already *got* the data as text, just keep it as text. Don't start messing around with the binary form when you don't need to.

Answer (score 0):

Java String Objects dont have encodings. An encoding, in this context, makes sense when associated with a  `byte[]`. try something like this:

```
byte[] utf8xmlBytes = originalxmlString.getBytes("UTF8");
```

and send these bytes.

EDIT: Also, consider the comment of Jon Skeet. It is usually a good idea to create XML using an API unless you have a very small amount of XML.